# WSO2 Governance Registry Endpoint Lookup Sample remote use case

Tags: wso2

There is an [Endpoint Lookup Sample](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Endpoint+Look-up+Sample) with the governance registry where an axis2 service uses the governance registry to look up the endpoint address of another service.

I want to deploy the axis2 service sample to a WSO2 Application server and still use the same WSO2 Governance server for storing the endpoint references.  Note that the Governance Registry is now remote to the application server.

**Questions:**

**1)** Do I just need to replace the RegistryService in the sample EndpointLookupServiceComponent with [RemoteRegistry](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Accessing+Registry+Remotely+through+API)?  E.g.

```
public class EndpointLookupServiceComponent {

    private static RegistryService registryService;

    public EndpointLookupServiceComponent() {
        registryService = new RemoteRegistry(
             new URL("https://my-greg-server:9443/registry"), "admin", "admin");
    }
    ...
}
```

**2)** Where would the following values typically be stored on the Application Server?

```
"https://my-greg-server:9443/registry"
"admin"
"admin"
```

Is is possible to store this type of information in a properties file, that is located external to the service archive (aar) file?  This approach makes it easy to change the values for different environments (DEV, TEST, PRD, etc).  Also, the properties file can then be protected using file system access controls to limit who can view the file.

What is the standard WSO2 approach for securely storing this type of configuration data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes you need to use RemoteRegistry instance to access the registry.
2. One method for doing this is to use [Registry](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Registry+Management) on WSO2 Application Server. So you can save your credentials as a registry resource and access this through registry api inside your service.